# How to post data with "Content-Type " header as "multipart/form-data"

Tags: java, android, http-headers, mime-types

I am trying to post data using `multipart/form-data`, but  it is not working with httpPost method. I have to send data as json string from the API,but it is giving bad response from server if I remove `content-type` header, response says that do not ave permission to edit following data,
I have to send 2 parameters from the API using `POST`,

below is my code:

```
public String webPostMultiForm(List<NameValuePair> params) {
        String postUrl = webServiceUrl;
        httpPost = new HttpPost(postUrl);
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            httpPost.addHeader("Cookie",appStatus.getSharedStringValue(appStatus.AUTH_KEY)); 
            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=assdsfdffafasf");
            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name= args");
            //httpPost.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding","chunked");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            Log.e(TAG, uee.getMessage());
        }
        Log.e(TAG,"WebGetURL: " + postUrl);
        try {           
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.getMessage() != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "httpClient.execute(httpPost) Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "httpClient.execute(httpPost) Exception: " + e.getClass().toString());
            }
        }
        try {
            strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.getMessage() != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getClass().toString());
            }
        }
        return strResponse;
    }
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong, or any other approach for this.

Answer (score 1):

how about http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ using it. 
you don't have to worry for anything.
Its very light weight.